# Find all numbers $n$ divisible by $a$ whose sum of digitis is $b$.

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I said to myself that it would be funny to find a natural number whose digits add to $69$ divisible by $420$. At first it might sound really silly but when I tried to find such a number it turned out to be way more difficult that I thought.

At first I tried the following, let $n$ be any number such that $420 \mid n$ and $s(n) = 420$, being $s(n)$ the sum of its digits. So for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $s(n) = s(420k) = s(2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7\cdot k) = 69$, but I noticed that this wouldn't take me anywhere since I don't know any way of solving for all possible $k$.

The next thing that I tried was finding a number using the divisibility criteria, so I found the number $777.777.777.420$ since it is clearly divisible by $7$, its digits add to a multiple of $3$, more specifically $69$, and its last two digits are a multiple of $4$ and $5$. So this method proved to be useful but not quite efficient.

My question is:

> Given any numbers $a$ and $b$, what is the easiest way to find natural numbers $n$ such that $a \mid n$ and $s(n) = b$?

Comment: You only need a number divisible by $21$ and digit sum $69.$ Then multiply by $100$ and get a number with the same digit sum and divisible by $420.$

Comment: A number with digit sum $69$ is automatically divisibly by $3,$ so you need a number with digit sum $69$ and divisible by $7.$

Comment: You can start with the digits $n=99,999,995.$ $n$ has digit sum $68,$ and is not divisible by $7.$ Find $k$ so that $10^kn\equiv -1\pmod 7.$ You can do so because $3$ is a generator modulo $7.$ Then $10^kn+1$ has digit sum $69$ and is divisible by $21,$ so $10^{k+2}n+100$ has digit sum $69$ and is divisible by $420.$ You can start with any beginning number $n$ with digits sum between $60$ and $68,$ excluding $69-7=62,$ and not divisible by $7.$ For each such $n$ you can find infinitely many $k.$

Comment: That is a clever method! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In this case, $k=5,$ and you get $999,999,950,000,100$ is such a number. This method won't be able to find a smallest example, because there are certainly examples which are not divisible by $100.$

Comment: $989,989,980$ is a relatively small example not divisible by $100.$ In particular, any example must end in $0$ and have at least $9$ digits. Bu there is probably a smaller value starting with $8.$

Comment: Probably the smallest is $899,899,980.$

Comment: The general problem is harder. The problem is digit sums is not really related to divisibility by any numbers other than $3$ and $9.$ it was convenient that $10$ was a generator modulo $7.$

Comment: There are, of course, no solutions when $a$ is divisible by $3$ (or $9$) and $b$ is not. Otherwise, if $b>2,$ I'd guess there are usually cases.

Comment: Your insight has been really helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is correct about the smallest n, I just verified and it is 899,899,980

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisHuppé, did you use a computer to verify it?

Comment: @ItsTrex Yes I did